# DYMO Label Web Service Printing Slow

Tags: dymo

I am noticing a delay of 5 to 15 seconds when  printing using the DYMO Label Web Service starting this morning, 4/23/2018.  This happens on multiple PCs on all browsers.  On a Mac it works fine.

The log at %LocalAppData%\DYMO\DLS8\DLSWebService.log seems to show the delay.  I don't see any errors in the Console beyond the usual *Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated* warning.

```
DYMO.DLS.Printing.Host.exe Information: 0 : PrintLabel: DYMO LabelWriter 450 Turbo
    DateTime=2018-04-23T17:08:34.9541652Z
DYMO.DLS.Printing.Host.exe Information: 0 : Loading barcode lib from C:\Program Files (x86)\DYMO\DYMO Label Software\MDYMOBarcode.dll
    DateTime=2018-04-23T17:08:50.1456872Z
DYMO.DLS.Printing.Host.exe Information: 0 : Utils.CreateLabelPrintParams(): printParams == null, creating default printParams based on printer type
    DateTime=2018-04-23T17:08:50.1547276Z
Status for job sent to printer DYMO LabelWriter 450 Turbo i False
DYMO.DLS.Printing.Host.exe Information: 0 : CheckServiceStatus
    DateTime=2018-04-23T17:08:51.3098746Z
DYMO.DLS.Printing.Host.exe Information: 0 : GetPrinters
    DateTime=2018-04-23T17:08:51.3269198Z
```

I tried updating to DLS8Setup.8.7.exe but this did not help.

Comment: Having the same issue. Fetching the label takes 15 seconds through the DLS web service tool. But if I browse to the label on our webserver manually it loads in less than a second. All PCs in our shipping department are having the same issue. OpenLabelFile is taking all the time. GetPrinters and PrintLabels are very fast as normal.

Comment: On Windows 10: I tried disabling Windows Defender "Real-time" and "Cloud-Delivered" settings but it did not help.  I added an exclusion for C:\Program Files (x86)\DYMO but that did not help.  Maybe there is another file outside this path the Anti-virus is fighting with?

Comment: I added a thread at https://serverfault.com/questions/908989/https-localhost41951-dymo-dls-printing-printlabel-takes-16-seconds

Comment: It is interesting, I checked some of the computers however they did not get any update since February but still have the same problem with others. I suspect that webservice is calling dymo link or certificate is getting corrupted or expire. I do not know why all of them having the same problem starting same time.

Comment: this totally worked - blocked the IP address with windows firewall.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I broke out Procmon and got to the bottom of this.

It appears to be due to the Dymo Label Service querying 128.30.52.100 (hans-moleman.w3.org) every time it was fed a label to validate its schema. We were not being rate limited by this service until today.

Setting an outbound firewall rule against this IP address for the DLS service executable fixed the issue.

Comment: One one machine it worked by having the ip blocked for the exe only.
On another I had to block the ip for all.
I didn't have time to debug further; user wants to work (strange idea...), but as they are not likely to have to access w3.org, not being developers, I'll just wait until dymo fixes the problem and remove the rule again.

Answer (score 2):

We just ran into this as well. Apparently the Dymo print service is trying to validate the generated xml against an xsd file. That file is not cached, so the print service is hitting w3.org to download it. Some time recently w3.org stopped responding to this request, making the xml validation slow as the request times out. So this is unrelated to any Windows update, update to the Dymo print service, or update to any browser.

If you run this command in Windows power shell as an administrator (and the path to your service is the same as ours), it will block the call to w3.org, causing it to fail fast instead of slow and move on to printing.

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "dymo-xsd-exclude" -Direction Outbound -Action Block -Program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dymo\DYMO Label Software\DYMO.DLS.Printing.Host.exe" -RemoteAddress 128.30.52.100
```

This is a short term solution. The correct solution is for Dymo to update their print service to include the xsd instead of calling across the internet for it.

Comment: Dymo is aware of the issue, and is working on a fix.

Answer (score 2):

I have been experiencing this issue too, here is the link to the Dymo Developers blog and the recommended solutions.

http://developers.dymo.com/2018/04/24/recent-issues-with-slow-printing/

The 2 solutions recommended on this blog are:

1) Prevent connections to 128.30.52.100 (http://www.w3.org/1998/XMLSchema)

2) Use the windows defender firewall to prevent DYMO.DLS.Printing.Host.exe from making outbound connections.

Answer (score 1):

FYI.  Dymo has a fix posted.  They released version 8.7.1 which fixes the slowness issues.  It can be downloaded from the developers site:
http://developers.dymo.com/2018/04/24/recent-issues-with-slow-printing/